# Is there any differents between $GLOBALS["test"] and global $test?

Tags: php, global

can any one please let me know the basic differences between

```
$GLOBALS["test"] and global $test
```

and, will it make sense that, if i use  `$GLOBALS["test"]` instead of `$_SESSION['test']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and, will it make sense that, if i use
>   $GLOBALS["test"] instead of
>   $_SESSION['test']?

No, **[session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)** is different thing from a variable that is available globally.

**$GLOBALS**

> An associative array containing
>   references to all variables which are
>   currently defined in the global scope
>   of the script. The variable names are
>   the keys of the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

**Explanation:**

`$GLOBALS` is an associative array available throughout your script, there is no need to use `global $test`

> Note: This is a 'superglobal', or
>   automatic global, variable. This
>   simply means that it is available in
>   all scopes throughout a script. There
>   is no need to do global $variable; to
>   access it within functions or methods.

Comment: @PHP-Prabhu: any php page actually. For example `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc are super global arrays available any time you want :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `$GLOBALS["test"]` and `global $test`. Both are pure evil and shouldn't be used.

### Why are they evil?

1. Suddenly your code becomes depended on some outer environment, its portability falls head over heels. It requires some variable defined somewhere, nobody know where, with some value, nobody know what's the proper value.
2. Imagine that `$test` is supposed to store an information about something, let's say: number of balls. Everything is fine until there is such a variable and it store what it's suppose to store. However what happen if you decide to delete that variable or use it for other purpose? Bah, fatal errors pop out of nowhere! You don't know what's going on, everything worked fine, you just change a variable's value and everything is falling apart.

Comment: you must be confusing it with register globals thereby declaring them evil.

Comment: I know what the register_globals is and what the global variable is. Both things are evil.

Comment: Care explaining why exactly is it "evil"

Comment: Can you suggest a better way to store database details such as hostname and dbname then please.