# what is the difference between GLOBALS and GLOBAL?

Tags: php, global

In PHP I want to know the differences between the GLOBAL and GLOBALS.

Some example:

```
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS` is an array, `global` is a PHP keyword. They essentially do the same thing but in a different way

Comment: but why we cant access the session and cookie variables by using $GLOBAL? i can access the variables which i have created using $GLOBAL.

Comment: Because that's not what $GLOBALS is there for. $GLOBALS is for variables defined in the global scope, no more no less. That's just the way it is.

Comment: See also: [Is there any differents between $GLOBALS\[“test”\] and global $test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888013/is-there-any-differents-between-globalstest-and-global-test)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That are two different things related to the same: global variables.

[**`$GLOBALS`**](http://php.net/GLOBALS) - PHP [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array representing the global variable table accessible as an array. Because it's a superglobal, it's available everywhere.

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

[**`global`**](http://php.net/global) - Keyword to import a specific global variable into the local variable table.

---

Then you asked:

> But why we cant access the session and cookie variables by using `$GLOBALS`?

That's wrong, you can access session and cookie variables by using `$GLOBALS`:

```
$GLOBALS['_SESSION']['session_variable_name']
```

However [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/_SESSION) is a superglobal as well, so you don't need to use either `$GLOBALS` nor `global` to access session variables from everywhere:

```
$_SESSION['session_variable_name']
```

Same applies to [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/_COOKIE).

Answer (score 6):

They are two different things.

[`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is a **keyword** which tells that the variable is from a global scope. E.g. if you're about to access a variable inside a function that's defined outside you'll need to use the global keyword to make it accessible in the function.

[`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) is a **[`superglobal`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array**. Superglobal simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script without the need of using the global keyword.

Answer (score 2):

$GLOBALS is an array and global is a keyword to declare or use global variables

Answer (score 1):

> $GLOBALS : An associative array containing references to all variables
>   which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The
>   variable names are the keys of the array
>
> GLOBAL/global is a keyword for setting a variable global.

References :

http://php.net/GLOBALS

http://php.net/global

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion in in between $GLOBAL and $GLOBALS.

$GLOBALS is a superglobal array that it is available in all scopes throughout a script without the need of using the global keyword.

You are trying to access the session and cookie variables by using $GLOBAL and that's wrong. Please use $GLOBALS instead. $GLOBAL is nothing.

But global is a keyword which tells that the variable is from a global scope.