# why the unset function is different between global and $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, reference, global-variables

## Question

**why the  unset function is different between global and $GLOBALS  ?**

here is my code , the  `$GLOBALS` version will echo nothing ,but the `global` will echo "hi".

```
//$GLOBALS version
<?php
function foo()
{
      unset($GLOBALS['bar']);
}
$bar ="hi";
foo();
echo $bar;
?>
```

**the code above echo nothing**

but when i change  `$GLOBALS['bar']` to  `global $bar` ,it echo **"hi"**

```
//global version
<?php
function foo()
{
        global  $bar;
        unset($bar);
}

$bar = "hi";
foo();
echo $bar;
?>
```

---

I have search in google and php manual , but it seems not detail about this problem .
[what is the difference between GLOBALS and GLOBAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035355/what-is-the-difference-between-globals-and-global)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true global variable imported inside a function scope with the `global` statement actually creates a reference to the global variable.  When you use `unset()` it unsets the variable that is referencing the global variable, the same as other references. When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed. For example:

```
$a = 1;
//assign a reference to $a
$b =& $a;
unset($b);
var_dump($a);
```

Yields: `int(1)` See [Unsetting References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php).

When you access `$GLOBALS` you are accessing a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array and unsetting the actual variable contained in the array.